# How to override theme style in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi i need text style for example `bodyText3`,like this

```
 bodyText3: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            height: 1.5,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: MyColors.black)
```

but in flutter we have  only this styles.

```
headline1,
headline2,
headline3,
headline4,
headline5,
headline6,
subtitle1,
subtitle2,
bodyText1,
bodyText2,
caption,
```

What should i do to add my new style ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Constant to define the style

```
const TextStyle bodyText3 = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 14,
  color: darkGrey,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
);
```

Use this constant in your Text's style property

```
 Text(
   'No',
   style: bodyText3,
),
```